Unwanted change in window raise behaviour (Gnome shell)
Just recently I found that when I click on a title bar, the window does not raise any more! This has always been the default behaviour, and what I want. I use "focus on hover", which conveniently changes the focus when I move the mouse, but it does (and should) not raise the window. To do that, a click is needed. Now I have to click somewhere inside the window, which might trigger other unwanted effects...
Hope this is understandable, and that the behaviour can be returned to what it was!
(Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, Gnome Shell 46.0)

This question is similar to: Where can I send feature requests?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. You could also discuss the issue in GNOME Discourse

Are you using an X11 session? If so, it may be this issue https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/2817

@yut23 X11 indeed. However, this might have been a glitch – the behaviour is now back to normal :)
